# How to shedule time machine backup

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine, scheduled-tasks

the standard backup interval for Time Machine is 1 hour.

In plist-file, i changed it to one day.

But, i need more tweak - to launch Time Machine backup at the specified time of day.

I prefer making backup, when my work day is completed.

How can i customize Time Machine do to so ?

Thanks!

Comment: Just curious, why would you want to change Time Machine to _not_ backup your work? Is it not safer to backup more often?  Also, does your work day really always finish at _exactly_ the same time every day? (What if you shutdown before this time?) Why not just put the TM icon in the menu bar and choose 'Back Up Now' just before you log off?

Comment: Yes. I thought about it.
It will be better for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.klieme.com/TimeMachineScheduler.html

It has an option to skip backup during specified hours.

For even more fine control:
http://timesoftware.free.fr/timemachineeditor/

Screenshot:

[image]